# Check Asterisk dynamic realtime (ARA) configuration with CLI

Tags: asterisk, voip

After configuring Asterisk dynamic realtime by adding the following lines to `/etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf`, is there any way of checking the resulting settings on the level of Asterisk CLI?

```
[settings]
iaxusers => odbc,mydb,iaxusers
extensions => odbc,mydb,extensions
```

For instance, `iax2 show users` and `dialplan show` still return what are apparently static configurations from `/etc/asterisk/iax.conf` and `/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf` respectively, even though `odbc show` reports `Connected: Yes` and tables (actually views) `iaxusers` and `extensions` in the SQL database `mydb` contain what should be appropriate rows.

I can see that dynamic realtime is at least partly active, because if I add another line e.g. for `iaxpeers` to `/etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf` while the corresponding table does not yet exists and then ([restart](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Stopping+and+Restarting+Asterisk+From+The+CLI) Asterisk gracefully from CLI and) issue `module unload chan_iax2.so`, `module load chan_iax2.so` I receive this warning:

```
WARNING[1426]: res_odbc.c:471 ast_odbc_find_table: 
Unable to retrieve database handle for table description 'iaxpeers@mydb'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166994/no-show-peers-after-configure-realtime-asterisk-with-odbc

Mainly it is about the rtpcachefriends option which must be set right.

Comment: Thx! That settles it for families `iax*` and `sip*`. Is there a similar recipe for showing a dynamic dialplan (`extensions`) as well?

Comment: Use "dialplan show" on CLI. As the changes in DB take effect immediately, I guess that command reflects the live state.

Comment: Unfortunately, your guess does not seem to be right.